# Why is record not deleting and response is 303 in Laravel 9, Inertia and Vue3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I have following code in route `web.php` file.

```
Route::resource('dailyrevenue', DailyRevenueController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

Then in my `DailyRevenueController.php`

```
 public function destroy(DailyRevenue $revenue)
{
    $revenue->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And in my vue3 code:

```
const submit = function (id) {
    const check = confirm("Are you sure to delete ?")
    if (check) {
       Inertia.delete(route('dailyrevenue.destroy',id), {
           id: id,
           method: 'delete',
           forceFormData: true
       })
    }
}
```

Finally in the template:

```
 <template #cell(actions)="{item: tax}">
        <form method="delete" @submit.prevent="submit(tax.id)">
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
          </form>
</template>
```

Now request reaches to the method. But nothing is deleted. The request sent is DELETE request. Instead of 302 response it sends back 303 (See others).

Community help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The redirect should be a 303 because the request is a DELETE request and (if properly implemented) a 302 request means a redirect to another DELETE request while a 303 request is a redirect to a GET request. (Most browsers don't implement this properly though)

Comment: My problem was with variable name. You can see following answer. Thanks for effort.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The reson behind it was the variable name. In url endpoint the variable name was decleared as `dailyrevenue` and in the method as `$revenue`.

You can find your url variable by typing `php artisan route:list`.

I found that the url variable name must match with variable name in method.

Hope this helps others too.